# how to remove Duplicate Values from listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-json

I am working in android application, in which i have to show data from json to listview. Right now i am getting the data from json but i am getting duplicate values in listview. How do i solve this Problem?

JSON VALUE

```
{"result":[{"messages":"i am user","sender_id":"5","rec_id":"admin"},{"messages":"i am admin","sender_id":"admin","rec_id":"5"},{"messages":"i am user again","sender_id":"5","rec_id":"admin"},{"messages":"i am admin again.","sender_id":"admin","rec_id":"5"}]}
```

Code

```
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

            id = c.getString("sender_id");
            ids = c.getString("rec_id");
            if(id.equals(session_id)&&ids.equals("admin")) {
                ss = c.getString("messages");
              }
            if(id.equals("admin")&&ids.equals(session_id)) {
                tt = c.getString("messages");
            }

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,tt);
            persons.put(TAG_MESSAGE,ss);
            personList.add(persons);

        }

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Messages.this, personList, R.layout.activity_message,new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_MESSAGE},new int[]{R.id.id,R.id.messag});

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {

                String postReceiverUrl = "http://piresearch.in/gpsapp/emp_message.php";
                //"http://progresscard.progresscard.in/progress_card/messages/get_messages.php";
                // HttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                // add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", session_id));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = resEntity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("tagconvertstr", "[" + result + "]");
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}
```

This is what i am getting [image]

Comment: try to clear personList before showing the list.

Comment: What do `tt` and `ss`  stand for, and where are they defined? Same for `id` and `ids`. Try to make your variable names more clear. In any case, it's not clear why they seem to be fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clear your arraylist` of previous data before adding new data in it.Check for size of list and if it is greater than zero clear your arraylist and then add HashMap in list.

Something like this

```
    if(personList.size()>0)
    personList.clear();
//now add your HashMap into list
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not got the proper solution but i have solved the problem by doing changing in hashmap.

```
HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();//globally Declare

   protected void showList(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

                id = c.getString("sender_id");
                ids = c.getString("rec_id");
                if(id.equals(session_id)&&ids.equals("admin")) {
                    ss = c.getString("messages");
                  persons.put(TAG_ID,tt);
                    }
                if(id.equals("admin")&&ids.equals(session_id)) {
                    tt = c.getString("messages");
                    persons.put(TAG_MESSAGE,ss);
                }





                personList.add(persons);

            }

            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Messages.this, personList, R.layout.activity_message,new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_MESSAGE},new int[]{R.id.id,R.id.messag});

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```